# How to set scroll position on uiwebview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to go to specify line on my uiwebview loaded.
I tried

> [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scrollTo(0.0,
>   100.0)"];

but it's not working. My webview still start with top of the page.
I just wonder its because I load the `UIWebview` inside `UIView`.
Check my code below on my `UIView`:

```
- (void)loadView {
    webview = [[WebViewDetail alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];        //initialize a mainView is a UIWebVIew
    webview.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    webview.kitab = self.kitab;
    webview.currentPasal = self.pasal;
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d", self.kitab, webview.currentPasal];
    self.view=webview;    //make the mainView as the view of this controller    
}
```

and I put the scroll positioning script on my `UIWebView`:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    int height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"] intValue];

    NSString* javascript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollBy(0, %d);", height];   
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
}
```

in this case I want to put my uiwebview go to the bottom of the page when the view is loaded.
But it's totally not working, why?
Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 20):

Try

```
webview.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 100);
```

Comment: i put it on webViewDidFinishLoad in my UIWebView and its not working, the scroll still show top of the page. any other idea?

Comment: @dejoong: are you sure your page is scrollable? try setting it on a timer firing after 1 second, to see if something might scroll after `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

Comment: tatz weird Dani, when i fire the method (contain webview.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 100);) every 1sec its working, but if i call the method directly its not working. do u kno why?

Comment: @dejoong: something is scrolling the view after `webViewDidFinishLoad`. I don't know how is that thing working, but I guess there is a later method you can tap to.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you set the view controller where you have your web view to be a `UIWebViewDelegate`, and declare this in the `@interface` of the header file (.h).

```
[yourWebView setDelegate:self];
```

Then, in the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method, insert this code:

```
[yourWebView.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, yourWebView.bounds.size.height + 100, 1, 1) animated:NO];
```