# Scrolling PDF programmatically in UIWebView

Tags: ios, pdf, ios6, uiwebview, scroll

I wanna to scroll(down) on a UIWebView(iPad Application), where I will display a local pdf file, programmatically.
I have added a UIWebView with the interface builder and linked it.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

This is my code for getting the pdf file and scrolling. The webViewDidFinishLoad function gets called.

```
@synthesize webView = _webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

    self.webView.delegate = self;
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}

#pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"didLoad");

    self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 500);
}
```

I am using the iOS SDK 6.1, the iOS deployment target is also 6.1.

Heres the log:

```
2013-04-23 09:23:08.742 PDFViewer[3834:c07] DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory.
2013-04-23 09:23:08.913 PDFViewer[3834:c07] didLoad
```

The UIWebView isn't scrolling. The pdf is still at the first page.

Comment: you want to scroll horizantally or vertically?

Comment: Yes, I am using iPad. I want to scroll down, so vertically.

Comment: hav you synthesized the webview object?

Comment: Yes I have.

@synthesize webView = _webView;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525256/how-to-set-content-offset-and-content-size-in-a-uiwebview

Comment: @Sunny this doesn't work really.

Comment: The problem is that self.webView.scrollView.contentSize is wrong. Its not the real contentSize.

[He has the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013754/uiwebview-content-height-not-accurate-in-scrollview-contentsize)

Comment: How did you fix the problem ?

Comment: I did not fix the problem. I was to lazy to search for a library, because this feature was only nice to have. Maybe they fix the bug with the contentSize in iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

already answered here --- [how to set scroll position on uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470991/how-to-set-scroll-position-on-uiwebview) , try calling content offset code snippet after a delay

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to set the `webView.scrollView.contentOffset`.

try this

```
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
```

Comment: The problem is that contentSize of webview.scrollView is equal to the screen size.